# fetching date from xml when format keeps on changing

Tags: java

How do I fetch a date from a XML document when it keeps on changing it's format using Java:

sometimes it will be

```
<date> from 1:00 pm to 2<00 pm it was raining<\date>
```

sometimes it will be

```
<date> between 1:00 pm and 2<00 pm it was raining<\date>
```

sometimes it will be

```
<date> from 1:00 pm & 2<00 pm it was raining<\date>
```

sometimes it will be

```
<date> from 1:00 to 2<00 pm it was raining<\date>
```

Comment: and the funky closing tags `<\ >`

Comment: The XML is no longer valid with a naked `<` in there.  Parsing invalid XML sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I think OP wrote this example by hand. Otherwise the first thing to look over is indeed the part that generates this xml.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't change the document to use the same format, you will have to use regular expressions. See [Pattern Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.